# Normal coordinate analysis in TRAVIS

Tags: spectroscopy, cp2k, aimd, travis

I have run a few AIMD calculations of some impurities trapped in a solid using [CP2K](https://www.cp2k.org) and [TRAVIS](http://www.travis-analyzer.de) to simulate the resulting infrared spectrum. While the infrared spectrum was simulated well, there is no indication as to what vibrations each peak corresponds to, so I cannot make the comparison between bulk phase AIMD and gas phase ab initio calculations.

One of the other features TRAVIS has, though, is a normal coordinate analysis (I assume) specifically for a situation like this. I attempted to run the normal coordinate analysis; however, one of the questions TRAVIS asks is to input a reference geometry.

The problem is that I have no idea what kind of reference geometry TRAVIS might want. For example, would it want an `.xyz` file (i.e., first line is number of atoms, second line is a comment line, and the cartesian coordinates follow), or simply a file with cartesian coordinates only? Should I take a random frame from the AIMD trajectory and use them as my reference geometry, or should I provide an optimised structure?

I have tried optimising one of the molecules in CP2K and using that as my reference structure (as was done in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4887082)), but, using a simple file with the cartesian coordinates of the impurity as input produced an error, saying:

```
Some atoms are not connected to the molecule

Molecule recognition failed
```

To my knowledge, there is currently no manual for TRAVIS, and the only tutorials I could find were about how to generate the IR spectra. I have reached out to the lead developer but not gotten a reply.

Does anyone have any experience doing this, or have any idea how to run this type of analysis in TRAVIS? Any help would be greatly appreciated!